# How to prevent a clutter of DTO objects?

Tags: api, oop, architecture, dto

I am using the [DTO pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html),
I am using an Auto Mapper library to even help map domain objects to DTO objects and it works well.

now that my application gets bigger i find myself in need for many different DTO object supporting different data needs.

lets say for example my application displays a list of employees each employee has an age property and a salary property in my application.

in my UI, on one page i show just a list of all the employees, in a different one i show a list of departments names the employees are in and the number of employees in each one, on a different page i show statistics on each avg salary, avg age total employee salary in the department etc...

considering i have many departments and many employees (lets say millions of employees and thousands of departments, too many for the client to calculate statistics on its own)

my question is how would you build an API that serves the client without creating many many DTOs? and without making unnecessary calculations? 
for example: in one flow counting the amount of employees in a department without calculating the avg salary in a case the avg salary is not interesting in order to make the api respond quicker and in another case calculating them both.

are there any other patterns to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

[GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) is one potential option.  It's a tool developed by Facebook for retrieving specific parts of their domain without retrieving the whole object.

This works well for retrieving pre-existing domain data.  It doesn't work as well for *calculating* data (you mention count of employees and avg salary).  As long as these are defined attributes (of department) you're fine.

Comment: do you know any patterns or tools to handle the calculations?

Comment: If your aim is for a client to be able to interrogate a dataset in a flexible way you might consider looking into the use of a Data Warehouse.